# How to make scrapy playwright retry on error

Tags: python, scrapy, playwright, scrapy-playwright

So I'm trying to write a crawler that uses Scrapy-playwright.
In previous project I've used only Scrapy and set `RETRY_TIMES = 3`. Even if I had no access to the needed resource the spider would try to send request 3 times and only then it would be closed.

Here I've tried the same but it seems it doesn't work. On the first error I get the spider is closing. Can somebody help me please? What should I do to make spider try to request url as many times as I need?

Here some example of my settings.py:

```
RETRY_ENABLED = True
RETRY_TIMES = 3
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 60
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = random.uniform(0, 1)

DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
}

TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

make sure to catch and log exceptions within your Playwright scripts. This will help you identify if the Playwright scripts themselves are encountering errors that trigger the spider to close.

```
RETRY_ENABLED = True
RETRY_TIMES = 3  
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 60 
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = random.uniform(0, 1)  # Introduce a random delay between requests

DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
    "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
}

TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"
```

You've set DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT to 60 seconds, which is a relatively long time. Ensure that the timeout is not too short for the types of requests you are making. If requests take a long time to respond, this could affect the retry behavior.